# get only text from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to get only the values of the keys in the below object

```
const params = [{"title":"How to code","author":"samuel","category":"categoery","body":"this is the body"}]
```

I find it difficult to do something like that

Comment: Please give a [mcve] of your difficult findings.

Comment: "get only text" and "get only values of keys" are different things. What's your required output, and what have you tried so far? The object is in an array if that's any help.

Comment: `Object.values(params)` will return an array of the values in the object. [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Comment: It's generally better here to ask "here's what I tried, it fails in this specific way, how do I fix it?" instead of "here's my problem, do the work for me".

Comment: No it won't. @ChrisRollins.

Comment: To get only the values from the object you can use `Object.values(params[0])`

Comment: @Andy you're right I didn't notice he enclosed the object in an array. So it would be `Object.values(params[0])`

Comment: Anyway, the OP wants either the text or the values of the _keys_ so that code maybe wrong, or is wrong depending on what the OP actually wants.

Comment: try `Object.keys` instead if it doesn't give you want you want

Comment: Welcome to SO, ISA. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: or just google it

Answer (score 0):

`Object.values(params)`

This will store the array of values of params object

Answer (score 0):

here is an example that list object value, using foreach in this case cause of you are used object through in the array ? hope that help you

```js
var params = [{"title":"How to code","author":"samuel","category":"categoery","body":"this is the body"}];
params.forEach(element=> {
        var _onjkey=Object.keys(element);
        _onjkey.forEach(key=>{
                console.log(element[key]);
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get values of the keys of the object by  [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```
const params = [{"title":"How to code","author":"samuel","category":"categoery","body":"this is the body"}]
params.map(data => {
  console.log(Object.values(data))
})
```